# how to call spring controller @RequestMapping from another action method passing form object along with the call

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I need to call another @RequestMapping from inside of a spring controller. Now I can easily do it by

```
    return "redirect:anotherMapping.htm";
```

But the I need to pass value in form object as well.

```
    @RequestMapping("/anotherMapping")
    public ModelAndView addUser(final @ModelAttribute("userLogin") UserLogin 
    userLogin, final HttpServletRequest request){
```

I need to pass userId in UserLogin. If I write  return "redirect:anotherMapping.htm";, then it invokes this controller method but form object is null.

Please help.

Comment: Look into `RedirectAttributes`.

Comment: Is it within the same controller?

Comment: I think there is no way to pass the form object too in the controller, is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use RedirectAttributes.

In below example, when foo is invoked and redirects to `/bar`, the model will contain `xyz=meow` attribute.

```
@RequestMapping(..)
public String foo(RedirectAttributes redir) {
  redir.addFlashAttribute("xyz", "meow");
  return "redirect:/bar";
}

@RequestMapping("/bar")
public String bar(Model model) {
  ..
}
```

If you find doing this too many time you might also [consider using `@SessionAttributes`](http://gerrydevstory.com/2014/03/04/using-sessionattribute-in-spring-mvc-to-implement-a-shopping-cart/)

Comment: 'i think this will definately help. I know I could use session or static variable to set the id and then set it explicitly in the form object, but those were not the best methodology. Also I think there is no way to pass the form object too in the controller, is it? Thanks bro for the help.

Comment: What do you mean "there is no way to pass the form object too in the controller"? You can use `@ModelAttribute` and `@SessionAttribute`